# Topological minor

Tags: graph-theory

What is the method of proof to show that a graph has a certain topological minor? I am in a rigorous second discrete math class where we were given this question:

**Prove or disprove: If G is bipartite and does not have K3,3 as
a topological minor, then G is planar.**

My idea was to show that G does not have K5 as a topological minor, then invoke Kuratowski's Theorem. The problem was I could not 100% think of a way to show that G has the K5 topological minor since we never went over a way of proof in lecture. Any help would be great!

Comment: If a graph is bipartite, then it does not have an odd cycle. If a graph has a $K_5$ as topological minor, does this imply that this graph has an odd cycle?

Comment: We were given in class the idea of a TH which my professor defined this way: Given H, a TH is a copy of H where edges have been replaced by independent paths. Then he went on to say that G has H as a topological minor if G has a TH as a subgraph. So I was thinking we could have a TH of K5 that does not have an odd cycle. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea to invoke Kuratowski after showing that $K_5$ is not a topological minor (TM) of $G$ would work, but there are bipartite graphs without $K_{3,3}$ as TM but with $K_5$ as TM.

Consider $K_5$ with once subdivided edges: bipartite and only having 5 branching vertices (that is of deg $\geq 3$) implies no $K_{3,3}$ as TM. And certainly not planar.

Comment: Thinking of [this debate](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13374/abuse-of-site-with-homework-assignments), the question was more than a month old already. Hope it is still useful :-)